# hdiv configuration

Tags: java, struts2, hdiv

If any one have integrated hdiv 2.0.4 for security integrity with struts 2.0.11, then please help me out on the configurations. I have integrated and configured it successfully and I am able to deployed successfully on my tomcat6.

Now, I am able to bring up the welcome/login page of my web-app. When I enter the login info, the action is called and after which I get null pointer exceptions. Pls, help me out to eliminate these exceptions.

> Nov 14, 2012 5:49:03 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet default threw exception
>   java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   org.hdiv.util.RequestUtilsHDIV.composeURL(RequestUtilsHDIV.java:108)
>   at
>   org.hdiv.util.RequestUtilsHDIV.addHDIVParameterIfNecessary(RequestUtilsHDIV.java:59)
>   at
>   org.hdiv.dispatcher.HDIVServletRedirectResult.doExecute(HDIVServletRedirectResult.java:122)
>   at
>   org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StrutsResultSupport.execute(StrutsResultSupport.java:178) at
>   org.hdiv.dispatcher.HDIVServletActionRedirectResult.execute(HDIVServletActionRedirectResult.java:200)
>   at
>   com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the request is not processed by HDIV's filter. All request must be processed by HDIV's filter before to use it in the view layer.

Comment: which filter your are talking about. I already have the interceptor listed in the struts.xml - <interceptor-ref name="editableValidation" />


And I have configured the following the filter in my web.xml 

<filter>
  <filter-name>ValidatorFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.hdiv.filter.ValidatorFilter</filter-class>
 </filter>

<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ValidatorFilter</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

Comment: Ok, this is the filter I was talking about. But it seems that the request is not procesed by it. Maybe it's a problem related with the url mapping of the filter and the url that you are requesting. In other words, debug if the request is proccessed by HDIV's filter.